# How do I get specific html element from current div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="sys-examination-field">
   <span class="sys-examination-name"><input onchange="checkCurrentDiv()" type="text" name="name" /></span>
   <span class="nad"><input type="checkbox" name="Nad" />NAD</span>
   <span class="comment"><input type="text" name="Comment" size="40" placeholder="Comment"/> </span>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="sys-examination-field">
...
</div>
```

What I want to know is this: 
  When I enter a value for the text box with name="name", is there a way to make this value the value of it's comment input (within that - current div)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="name"]').on('keyup',function(){
  $('input[name="Comment"]').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

or

```
$('.sys-examination-field').on('keyup','input[name="name"]',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this
     .closest('div')
     .find( 'input[name="Comment"]' )
     .val( $this.val() );
});
```

(Edited to reflect refinements of the question suggested in comments.)

Comment: "...to make this value the value of **it's comment input (within that div)**?"

Comment: @Andreas: See above. OP's question is not really clear about what the desired behavior actually is.

Comment: Hi @Robusto, all divs carry thesame kind of elements. So I would want to target element for current div. Thanks.